# Magento : merge two collections and keep the same sorting

Tags: sorting, magento, collections, merge

Can someone help me please ?

I have two collections and i want to merge them into only one keeping the same sorting :

```
$collection_with_image = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addCategoryFilter($category)
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*') 
    ->addAttributeToFilter('small_image', array('like' => '/%/%/%'))
    ;

$collection_basique_without_image = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addCategoryFilter($category)
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter(array(
        array('attribute' => 'small_image', 'null' => true),
        array('attribute' => 'small_image', 'eq' => 'no_selection')
        ), 
        '', 
        'left')
    ;
```

I've tried [this solution](http://www.gurutheme.com/blog/2013/06/23/merge-magento-product-collections/) but it doesn't keep the same sorting :/

the final results thas i want is, only one collection how contain at the first positions product with pictures.

Thanks for all

Answer (score 0):

```
$collection_with_image = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
->addCategoryFilter($category)
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addAttributeToFilter(array(
    array('attribute' => 'small_image', 'null' => true),
    array('attribute' => 'small_image', 'eq' => 'no_selection'),
    array('attribute' => 'small_image', 'like' => '/%/%/%')       
    ),
```

);

This will output a WHERE clause of the format:

```
WHERE ((small_image LIKE 'value') OR (small_image eq 'no_selection') OR (small_image eq 'null'))
```

Comment: tnx for your answer, but it will not keep the sorting that i want (products with image first :/ )